# RL circuit short circuit issue

Tags: circuit-analysis, short-circuit

Was trying to solve the below circuit. But couldn't get any thought process going on. 
[image: Circuit]

Voltage source is square pulse alternating between 0 V and 5 V with period of 3 seconds.

So tried to simulate the circuit and i got the error as in figure. What might be the issue in this circuit?
[image: Simulation result]

Comment: Do your inductors have series resistance? It might be complaining because DC resistance to ground is zero (just a guess, I'm not familiar with Spectre).

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using the inductors which are ideal I
(i.e. from analogLib). For a DC solutions the inductors are replaced by shorts, therefore the simulator can't find a solution because you are shorting your source.

Add a small resistor in series with your voltage source.

As pointed out by Neil_UK another problem is the loop of inductors by itself. Since the current is not determined this leads to another error. So there are actually two problems. Splitting the circuit one gets two error messages.

```
Fatal error found by spectre during topology check.
    FATAL: The following branches form a loop of rigid branches (shorts) when added to the circuit:
        V0:p (from 0 to 0)
        L2:1 (from net4 to 0)
```

[image]

Comment: it's not so much 'shorting your source', but note that the source is also zero impedance, so it's a loop of zero impedance. The solution is the same, put a sniff of resistance into any zero impedance loop, 1m\$\Omega\$ is plenty.

Comment: A loop of zero impedance wouldn't be a problem. But as soon as you short a source, you force two different conditions (voltage equal to zero and voltage equal to the source voltage). Therefore you get an error.

Comment: Yes i used ideal inductors. 
Do inductors get short circuited under dc voltage also? 
What will be the nature of the circuit under t=0+ and at infinite time? 
Will the inductor get short circuited at t=0+?

Comment: Even for a transient simulation you need a starting point, which is the DC simulation. So you can't get around that problem. But as Neil_UK suggested, just add a small resistor in series. There are no ideal inductors anyway. Less advanced SPICE implementations have even more restrictions so you should avoid too ideal circuits.

Comment: Yes i understood the get around method. 
However getting more confused why inductors are behaving as a short circuit here. As the current passing through it is varying right?

Comment: Every simulation needs to start at some point in time, so we need an initial solution, for this solution it assumed that some steady condition is reached. Capacitors are charged (and can therefore be removed) and inductors have a certain *constant* current and can be removed (=short circuit) too. For transient, AC or whatever simulation the devices are still present.

Comment: So what i understood is, under steady state, the two inductors are short circuited, and hence once the Voltage is applied at t=0, KVL is violated . Is that right?

If i replace the voltage source with a dc current and inductors with a capacitor, would there be a problem? As the capacitors would be O.C and the current source does not have a path to flow.

Comment: If the current can't flow there is a problem. It could be that the simulator adds a resistor (Gmin) automatically, then you would have a path for the current.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36602/discussion-between-anjana-verma-and-mario).

Comment: I am also curious about the Laplace analysis of the same circuit for finding the voltage across L2, interestingly i couldn[t find any issues while solving. Is it that such issues does not show up in LT analysis or have i made any mistake?

Comment: @Mario no, I beg to differ, but I may be wrong, and an experiment on your favourite simulator would give the answer. It's the **loop** of zero impedance that's the problem, not one of them being a source. The reason is that such a loop makes the matrix that needs to be solved degenerate, therefore uninvertable. The experiment would be to connect a delta of inductors to a source with a resistor, and see what happens during the DC solve step.

Comment: @Neil_UK. You are right, the loop could indeed be another problem. Still, I think that voltage sources with a short don't work either. It would really be interesting to give it a try.

Comment: @Neil_UK . Which matrix are you talking about? Is there any reference material or particular textbooks that i can refer to get more hindsight ?

Comment: @Neil_UK. I couldn't help but doing a quick simulation. Actually there are two problems. Good catch!

Comment: Please explain!

Comment: I've updated the answer.

Comment: @AnjanaVerma I've had a quick google, and not found any links worth posting yet. Basically when you do mesh analysis, you end up with a shed-load of simulataneous equations. Humans solve them usually by eliminating equations one at a time. Algorithms solve them by constructing the matrix equation Ax = b, then writing x = b/A. If you have a loop of zero impedances, two rows or columns of A end up dependant, and the system becomes unsolvable, as you would expect if you can't tell manually which way current is flowing through two zero ohm branches.